# Bound on the number of isolated rest points of a vector field

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry

Let $P(x,y,z)$ be a homogeneous polynomial of degree $n$. Consider the vector field
$$F_P = \left[ \begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
\frac{\partial P}{\partial x} - nxP\\
\frac{\partial P}{\partial y} - nyP\\
\frac{\partial P}{\partial z} - nzP
\end{array} \right].$$
I want to prove that if $n$ is fixed, the number of isolated rest points of this vector field $F_P$ is uniformly bounded over all homogeneous polynomials $P$ of degree $n$. What is the bound for $n=3$?

Thank you, in advance, for any suggestion, comment, or response!

Comment: I do not understand what **uniformly bounded over all homogeneous polynomials $P$ of degree $n$** means.

Comment: This question is related to structurally stable vector fields.

Comment: I suppose it means: *For all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ there is a constant $C>0$ such that for all homogeneous polynomials $P$ of degree $n$  we have $\# \{a\in \mathbb{R}^3\vert DF_P(a) = 0\} \le C$.*

Comment: @JanBohr: Thanks! I guess you mean $\{a \in \mathbb{R}^3 | F_P(a) = 0 \}$, right?

Comment: You're right. That makes more sense.